# Migrate Anaconda packages to `venv` virtual environment

Tags: windows, pycharm, anaconda, python-venv, python-3.7

I have installed Anaconda recently in a new Windows computer. I have no experience with managing installed packages in Windows, but in Linux. I created a new project with PyCharm and chose to use as interpreter Python 3.7 that I installed separate from the Python 3.6 version that Anaconda comes with. Now I want to be able to use Anaconda modules such as numpy or pandas in my PyCharm Project, that is using a virtual environment set up in a PyCharmProjects folder.

I fail to understand how exactly should I do it. What is that I have to copy or run to migrate the Python packages installed in Conda to my Virtual environment created from a clean independent install of Python 3.7? When I try to import them they don't work. Do I have to create a new project and migrate the files or can I do it without that?

#### Edit

Also, I am very unclear about how I can run Python36 that Anaconda installed. There is no conda command in Windows and python runs python27. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that using Python in Windows goes a bit differently than in Linux/MacOS. In order to change the default version that runs when `python` command is executed, one has to run the command `regedit` and Find (`Ctrl+F`) Python.exe, and change the path to default Python interpreter that one wants to use. Python installed by Anaconda can be found in Anaconda's folder in `C:\ProgramData` (if installation was for all users, if not its probably in some other folder in `C:\Users\[User]`.

As for the other part of the question, I'm not sure but I think packages have to be re-installed in the virtual environment, unless you know how to copy the files one by one. Also, it's important to be careful with the version compatibility. In my case, the two Python installations are different versions, so it might not work the trick to copy the files. Other option is to change where the interpreter runs; if in that folder the packages are installed, the installation will succeed. You can also change Python's path to find packages; but that is something that must be done programatically and is not very handy to have to be running those lines of code each time.

[image: PyCharm project creation window]
When creating a project (or even when the project is already created) you can choose to change the interpreter to Anaconda's Python, **even if you are not using conda as a package manager, but virtualenv by Python**. That'd be the trick for me. Aditionally, PyCharm also natively integrates package installation into the virtual environment in a GUI menu.

If anyone has a better answer/explanation, I'm looking forward to getting to know it, but in the meanwhile that is the conclusion I have arrived to.